# How to integrate with Jira ondemand

Tags: api, jira, bug-tracking, ondemand

I'm working on a web application that I need to Integrate with Jira bug tracking tool. I have successfully integrated with the applications hosted at jira, but now I have to integrate with the JIRA hosted on other server (not the .atlassian ones).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hosted solution will have the same capabilities as a REST API. So just point to the appropriate URL and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to integrate with the REST API, just try hitting it to see if its enabled.

If it isn't enabled, make sure the 'Allow Remote API Calls' is turned ON under Administration > General Configuration.